# How to write a JPA function or Query for table created by @ManytoMany mapping?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called `User` like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<User> friends;
}
```

This user will have friends from the same entity therefore Many to Many mapping to the same table.

Hibernate has created a table which contains two columns like this:

[please view the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IRQa.png)

The first column is the id of the actual user and the second column is the id of the friend.

Now I need to query this new table by passing the id (of the actual user) to get the list of their friends like this

```
select user.username from user where user.id in(
select user_friends.friends_id from user_friends where user_friends.user_id = 1);
```

`user` is the original user table and `user_friends` is the table created by hibernate for Many to Many mapping.

The query I've written above is to find all the username of a user with id=1. (Inner query is to get friends_id from joined table and upper query is to fetch username from the id)

My question is how to implement this query in Repository as the table is a result of Many to Many relationship and it doesn't have a separate Repository as User has.

I've no Idea how this works as this is the first time I'm using JPA and Hibernate for Many to Many mapping.

Comment: `select f.username from User u join u.friends f where u.id = :id`

Comment: could you please elaborate what is happening here. Also, instead of query can we define a JPA method directly?

Comment: You are confusing JPA with Spring - there are no jpa methods you define. Spring repository methods though use JPA queries to return results - see the @Query annotation in spring for examples which you could use to run that JPQL query to get a list of usernames

Comment: @Chris Oh got you. But I was asking if we can write a method instead of writing a query. Spring scans method name, converts to query and gets us the results right. So I wanted to know if we can write such methods in this case.

Comment: From https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods , it doesn't look like Spring can build that query for you based on the name - you'll want to define a method and have it using the query with the query annotation (or other option).

Answer (score 0):

In many-to-many relationships rather than using the `@JoinColumn` annotation you should use the `@JoinTable` one. Explaining this can be a little confusing so I'll try to be as graphic as I can using your own example.

#### The `UserFriend` entity

First of all, you have to know that now JPA needs two different entities: `User`, which you already have, and a second one named `UserFriend`, which will represent a row from the `user_friends` table that was created to hold the relationship between users.

This entity will obviously have the fields `userId` and `friendsId`, just like the corresponding table does. It also needs to be decorated with the `@IdClass(value = UserFriendPK.class)` annotation. See the next section to understand where this `UserFriendPK` class comes from.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_FRIENDS")
@IdClass(value = UserFriendPK.class)
public class UserFriend implements Serializalbe {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   private long userId;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "friends_id")
   private long friendsId;

   // constructor, getters and setters...
}
```

#### The `UserFriendPK` composite key

In order to query a `UserFriend` entity programmatically from JPA you will need an instance of a custom composite key class. Note that the `user_friends` table doesn't have an identity column, that's because the primary key is actually a composite primary key made from the combination of the `user_id` and the `friend_id` columns. So we'll basically make our own custom class to mimic this behavior.

Composite primary key classes must meet the following requirements:

- The class must be public
- It must implement the `Serializable` interface
- It must have a no-args public constructor
- Its field names must match those of the entities it refers to
- It must override the default `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods

```
public class UserFriendPK implements Serializable {
   private long userId;
   private long friendsId;

   // constructor, getters and setters, equals() and hasCode()...
}
```

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys) you can find some more information about this topic.

#### The `@JoinTable` annotation

Coming back to the `User` entity, now we have to set the many-to-many field that will hold the user's friends. As I said at the beginning of the answer, instead of the `@JoinColumn` annotation, we must use the `@JoinTable` one. This one is a bit confusing to explain, so i'll write the code first:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {
   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "USER_FRIENDS"
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friends_id",
                               referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private Collection<User> friends;

   // rest of fields, methods, etc...
}
```

So... what's going on here!? Basically, the `@JoinTable` annotation has three elements: `name`, `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns`.

- The first one is quite obvious, it's the name of the table that holds the relationship between a user and their friends.
- The `joinColumns` element states the names of the columns that refer to the id of the user on the `user_friends` table (`user_id`) and in the user itself (`id`).
- The `inverseJoinColumns` is just the opposite. The names of the columns that refer to the id of the friend in the `user_friends` table (`friends_id`) and in the friend entity (`ìd`).

#### Retrieving the entities

Now you have everything set up. It's time to retrieve those entities! To do so, you just have to find the user that you wish to check and call the `getFriends()` method on it.

There are several ways to do this. Hibernate has something called HQL (Hibernate Query Language) which is basically a way to pass a SQL query in a String through a method.

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
List results;
List friends;

try {
   String hql = "FROM users u WHERE u.id = :id";
   Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
   query.setParameter("id", 1);
   results = query.list();

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTace();
}

if (results != null) {
   User user = results.get(0);
   friends = user.getFriends();
}
```

If there's something in this last part of the code that you don't understand, check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm).

Hope this helps!